# Add data from comand line in Ansible task

Tags: command-line, ansible

I have some task:

```
---

- name: Ansible multiple replace data in file {{ path_agentd_conf }}
  replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  with_items:
    - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "Server=127.0.0.1", replace: "Server={{ ip_zabbix_server }}"}
    - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "ServerActive=127.0.0.1", replace: "ServerActive={{ ip_zabbix_server }}"}
    - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "Hostname=Zabbix server", replace: "Hostname={{ ansible_hostname }}"}
    - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "# HostMetadata=", replace: "HostMetadata=73dc46da7abd1908951478965ca5b5be"}
```

And also i have variables in path `/etc/ansible/roles/zabbix/zabbix-agent/agent/roles/agent/defaults/main.yml`

```
---
# defaults file for agent

dir_download: /home/
path_agentd_conf: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
url_zabbix: https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.0/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_6.0-1+ubuntu20.04_all.deb
deb_zabbix: zabbix-release_6.0-1+ubuntu20.04_all.deb
ip_zabbix_server: 95.111.111.111
```

My first goal is, to use command line when I started playbook and change in line `ip_zabbix_server:` IP, for example `ansible-playbook start.yaml -ip 55.55.55.55` and this IP should be replaced IP `95.111.111.111`.

And second, is, to add also from command line in line `- {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "# HostMetadata=", replace: "HostMetadata=73dc46da7abd1908951478965ca5b5be"}` after numbers `73dc46da7abd1908951478965ca5b5be` some worlds `lxd mysq`

`- {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "# HostMetadata=", replace: "HostMetadata=73dc46da7abd1908951478965ca5b5be lxd mysq"}`

I do not know is it passable in ansible or not ? I know that for example in bash it is possible, when we are using in bash scripts variables `$1 $2` etc.

Could you please help? Thank you!

Comment: declare var ip_value="95.111.111.111" in your's playbook, use extra-args in command line, ansible-playbook start.yaml -e "ip_value="55.55.55.55" https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to modify this "default" value in the variables with one in command line:

Taking into consideration the order of the variables as you might know, Command Line prevails over what's already defined in roles, plays, tasks, defaults, etc.

So, for get that result you need to run your playbook like this:

`ansible-playbook start.yaml -e "ip_zabbix_server=55.55.55.55"`

basically it should be similar to bash but with the parameter -e | --extra-vars

For the second part I'm not sure but I would try if I can set that as variable and do in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

> My first goal is, to use command line when I started playbook and change in line `ip_zabbix_server`

This a very common scenario of overriding a default role variable. You can have a look at [where to put a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) for all possible solutions.

But in your specific case, to override from the command line, you would use an `extra-vars`:

```
ansible-playbook start.yaml --extra-vars ip_zabbix_server=55.55.55.55
```

> And second, is, to add also from command line in line `- {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "# HostMetadata=", replace: "HostMetadata=73dc46da7abd1908951478965ca5b5be"}`

That one is trickier for 2 reasons:

- you have hard-coded the list of dictionaries inside the task which makes it hard (not to say impossible) to overide
- passing a long list of dictionaries directly on the command line is not really user friendly (but possible).

My below proposition is not the only solution and you can adapt depending on your exact requirement (see above link on variable precedence).

First add a new default variable in `roles/agent/defaults/main.yml`:

```yaml
my_replace_list:
  - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "Server=127.0.0.1", replace: "Server={{ ip_zabbix_server }}"}
  - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "ServerActive=127.0.0.1", replace: "ServerActive={{ ip_zabbix_server }}"}
  - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "Hostname=Zabbix server", replace: "Hostname={{ ansible_hostname }}"}
  - {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "# HostMetadata=", replace: "HostMetadata=73dc46da7abd1908951478965ca5b5be"}
```

Then modify your task to use that var:

```yaml
- name: Ansible multiple replace data in file {{ path_agentd_conf }}
  replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_replace_list }}"
```

We are then in the exact same situation as above for the zabbix server ip and the list can be overridden with an extra var in your command. The easiest way here is to declare the var in a separate file, e.g. `my_list_override.yaml`

```yaml
my_replace_list:
  - {path: "/toto", regexp: "from", replace: "to"}
  - {path: "/titi", regexp: "a", replace: "b"}
```

You can then easily use that file to override your variable:

```
ansible-playbook start.yaml --extra-vars @/path/to/my_list_override.yml
```

Now, if you really want to pass that variable directly on the command line, it is possible but you will have to pass it as a correct json which is probably not the most user friendly method:

```
ansible-playbook start.yaml \
  --extra-vars '{"my_replace_list":[{"path":"/toto","regexp":"from","replace":"to"},{"path":"/titi","regexp":"a","replace":"b"}]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

I just deleted line `ip_zabbix_server: 95.217.188.202` from the file `/etc/ansible/roles/zabbix/zabbix-agent/agent/roles/agent/defaults/main.yml`, then add to lines variables `{{ ip }}`

```
- {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "Server=127.0.0.1", replace: "Server={{ ip }}"}
- {path: "{{ path_agentd_conf }}", regexp: "ServerActive=127.0.0.1", replace: "ServerActive={{ ip }}"}
```

and after I am using command `ansible-playbook agent.yml --extra-vars ip=77.77.77.77` to add 77.77.77.77 to the line `Server=127.0.0.1"` and `ServerActive=127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Since you removed the default server ip from defaults role variable, the above will fail with an undefined variable error if you don't provide the given var on the command line (or any other mean). You should secure this by providing a default value either with an entry for `ip` in `roles/agent/defaults/main.yml` or by default the var in your list if it does not exist => "Server={{ ip | default('1.2.3.4') }}". An other option would be to use the `assert` module to fail with a relevant message if the var is not defined.